# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character

Tags: firebase, flutter

I couldn't  transform my fetched the data,

But no errors showing, I have added a print statement to find error where it occurs

```
   Future<void> fetchAndSetProduct() async {
        final url =
            Uri.https('shopda-83b00-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com', '/products');
        try {
          print("karan  oneonofne ");
          final response = await http.get(url);
          final extractData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
          final List<Product> loadedProduct = [];
          extractData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
            loadedProduct.add(Product(
                id: prodId,
                title: prodData['title'],
                description: prodData['description'],
                price: prodData['price'],
                isFavourite: prodData['isFavourite'],
                imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl']));
          });
          print(loadedProduct[1]);
          _items = loadedProduct;
          notifyListeners();
        } catch (error) {
          throw (error);
        } finally {
          print('object');
        }
      }
```

[image]

then I changed like this
[image]

Still, I couldn't get data.I think I couldn't change HTML to Jason

Comment: There is something that went wrong with your API. It returns html

Comment: You expect some kind of objects while you got something else.

Comment: It's likely that your API call was malformed, so instead of receiving a JSON response, you received an HTML error page.  Instead of using `Uri.https`, I recommend using `Uri.parse` with an URL that you've tested with a browser.

Comment: It doesnt work .could you help me and rewrite the code. it gives HTML instead of Json

Answer (score 1):

I found it Please change HTML file Json by simply

```
final url =
            Uri.https('shopda-83b00-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com', '/products.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fetch data from your Realtime Database by using the direct link.

This requires you to sign in and that is the HTML page it returns.

You should use the [firebase_database](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database) package to fetch the data from the database.

You should update your `fetchAndSetProduct` method to this:

```dart
Future<void> fetchAndSetProduct() async { 
  try {
    ...

    final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot =  await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('products').once();
    final extractData = json.decode(dataSnapshot.value) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    ...
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  } finally {
    ...
  }
}
```